# Connect to Active Directory Database via mySQL

Tags: mysql, active-directory

I'm trying to create a script either as a .bat file which can be added to a task in task scheduler or a stored procedure. The script would look at all the users of Active Directory with a particular attribute and I can then import or update those users in another system/database.

Is it possible to connect to the database of Active Directory by MySQL? If so, can someone point me in the right direction on how I would achieve this? I'm more of a Javascript / PHP guy.

Apologize for the vague question.

Comment: *"Is it possible to connect to the database of Active Directory by MySQL? "* No *"If so, can someone point me in the right direction on how I would achieve this? I'm more of a Javascript / PHP guy."* But PHP can with the [LDAP Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php)

Comment: @RaymondNijland interesting...